# Idris, typed addition (incrementation)

Tags: function, types, numbers, idris, proof-of-correctness

How can I write function like this

```
data Wrap : Nat -> Type where
  Wrp : n -> Wrap n

addOne : (n : Nat) -> Wrap (S n)
addOne {n} = Wrp (S n)
```

in a form like this

```
addOne : (n : Nat) -> S n
addOne {n} = S n
```

or something similar?

Thanks

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "in a form like this"? What does that alternative form do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addOne : (n : Nat) -> S n` wouldn't be valid, as the return type wouldn't be a type, but a value. Closest thing to what you might want would be

```
addOne : (n : Nat) -> (k : Nat ** k = S n)
addOne n = (S n ** Refl)
```

where `addOne` would return a tuple of some `Nat` and a proof, that this `Nat` is indeed `S n`. Or proving that property afterwards:

```
addOne : (n : Nat) -> Nat
addOne n = S n

addOneIsSucc : (n : Nat) -> addOne n = S n
addOneIsSucc n = Refl
```